# Editing CSS Media Queries in Wordpress

Tags: css, media-queries

this is my first time trying to do media queries on my own. I can usually learn this stuff pretty easily, but I've been searching forever and there's something I'm not understanding. I work through Wordpress and I am trying to edit the styles of content within a media query. I use The7 theme which is auto responsive, but there are several edits I want to make within the content that ONLY apply on devices.

How do I make

```
.element style {
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 48pt;
line-height: 50pt;
}
```

become

```
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 20pt;
line-height: 21pt;
max-width: 480px;
```

in a media query? Do I assign a div class like .class1 to the normal code and then add a second class that overrides it in a media query like .class2 .class1? How do I do this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The class stays the same. It would be something like this:

```
.element {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 48pt;
    line-height: 50pt;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* change the breakpoint above to suit your needs */ 
    .element{
        font-size: 20pt;
        line-height: 21pt;
        max-width: 480px;
    }
}
```

Comment: So in my frontend editor do I assign a div class and then style it? Because to add content I just add a text block and style it in there. Ex: <p style="stuff here> text here </p> -- Should I do something live <div class="name"> and style it in the css?

Comment: Yes, avoid inline styling at all costs.